# Query enum in hibernate throws DataException: Bad value for type int : t

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, hql

I have a table with an Enum type attribute mapped like this:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
@Column(name = "status")
private Enums.Status status;
```

Where the Enums.Status is

```
public enum Status {
    CHECKED(1),
    DISABLED(2),
    INACTIVE(3);
    int id;
    // constructor + getter
}
```

And the column status from the database is stored as type `int4`

I am querying the table with the following HQL:

```
Query q = session.createQuery(" from Users where status=:account");
query.setParameter("account", Enums.Status.CHECKED);
List<Users> users = query.list();
```

The above code works fine on my testing server, but when on the production server it throws the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Bad value for type int : t
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.getInt(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType$OrdinalEnumValueMapper.getValue(EnumType.java:358)
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType.nullSafeGet(EnumType.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeGet(CustomType.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2873)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1668)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1600)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1500)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:712)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:940)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
```

I tried replacing the enum parameter with its `.ordinal()` value, but received another exception. I tried looking up the differences between the testing server and the production server, but they both use the same java version, hibernate library, datatypes for the table and table content.

Has anyone ever encountered any similar issue or has any idea how it could be fixed?

Comment: can you show your enum class?

Comment: It looks like there is a value in the production server, which is not mapped by the enum. If you've got an enum with three enumerations - with ORDINAL - there should only the three values 1 2 and 3 in the DB

Comment: @Patrick I added it to the question

Comment: @JanPiel Both databases contain only values of 0 and 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out the problem. In our case the production server has multiple schemas and a database update failed on one of them, resulting in a field having a different data type then its hibernate mapping.

In case anyone gets here looking for an answer to the same error, try the following:

- For enums, verify that the datatype in the db is integer for mapping @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL) (or varchar for EnumType.STRING)
- Verify that all other data types of that table match the hibernate mapping
- Verify that the values inside the db do not exceed the number of items in the enum
- Verify data in all schemas (if you are using multiple)
- If you are experiencing this error on one server and not on another, check for the following differences: jdk version, hibernate-core version, database driver version. If they are all the same, try dumping the database from one server to another

Comment: Maybe edit your original question to contain this information, because a reader may miss it here. Or I guess you can make sure to accept this answer after 48 hours.

Comment: @carbontax I added it as an aswear since this is the solution to my question. I will accept it once I can.

Answer (score 1):

With Java Enums, the term `ordinal` does not refer to an `id` property, but to a built in property of the `Enum` class. See [JavaDocs for the `ordinal()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal()).

> Returns the ordinal of this enumeration constant (its position in its enum declaration, where the initial constant is assigned an ordinal of zero). Most programmers will have no use for this method. It is designed for use by sophisticated enum-based data structures, such as EnumSet and EnumMap.

**Note that the first ordinal is 0 (zero) not 1**

Don't be calling the `ordinal()` method yourself; let Hibernate do that.

Comment: I know what ordinal refers too. I said I tried calling it just to see if it would work. The original code (which throws that error), does not call `.ordinal()`

Comment: Sorry, I was confused. Thought you had mapped the `id` property of the Enum